# How do one "force" VNAV climb mode through a set altitude constraint?

Tags: boeing-737, vnav

Let's say I'm flying out of EGPH, there is a first altitude constraint at 6000ft automatically set by the FMS. After departure, I will engage my VNAV to climb on profile.

VNAV will hold at 6000ft no matter what I set at or above 6000ft on the MCP.
What is the procedure in that case if ATC clears me above 6000ft to ask VNAV to continue climbing to the newly assigned altitude past the 6000ft constraint?

So far I have pushed LVL CHG and manually set my speed to 250 then 296 to keep the profile.
Any way to do that with VNAV?

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

Pressing ALT INTV will clear the 6,000' constraint and allow VNAV to resume a VNAV Climb immediately -- assuming that

- the Cruise altitude is something higher than that, and
- the MCP selected altitude is also above 6,000'.

The segment at 6,0000' would be flown in VNAV Path, so the active vertical mode remains VNAV, and ALT INTV is immediately available. When it's pressed, you'd see the 6,000' constraint on the LEGS page go away, and the active vertical mode switches to VNAV Speed, and you're climbing.

As one old head explained it, "ALT INTV is a 'Delete' key."